# What's the best user registration library to integrate WordPress?

Tags: php, user-registration, library

I'm looking for a library that can handle user registration (name, address, e-mail etc.) into my existing WordPress website. What options exist today, or will I have to pull my own?

Comment: I am not sure about _library_ part. WordPress has native and extensible capabilities to register users. Do you have a need to completely replace that functionality for something else with different specs?

Comment: My client wishes that his customers to be able to sign up with their personal information (following the directives by our local laws of course.) If I can easily extend the native solution that might be a way to go -- otherwise I was hoping if a plugin existed of similar kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tutorial on extending user information I have stored in bookmarks: [Adding and using custom user profile fields](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields). Take a look and see if it fits your needs.

PS I am not following developments in user functionality closely so there might have been changes/improvements since tutorial was published.